# Source multiple files in one folder in Rstudio

Tags: r

I have a folder with multiples R functions. I would like to source all these functions in R studio. I tried the following code, but it does not work. I found the following code here ()

```
sourceFolder <- function(folder, recursive = FALSE, ...) 
{ 
    files <- list.files(folder, pattern = "[.][rR]$", 
                        full.names = TRUE, recursive = recursive)
    if (!length(files))
        stop(simpleError(sprintf('No R files in folder "%s"', folder)))
    src <- invisible(lapply(files, source, ...))
    message(sprintf('%s files sourced from folder "%s"', length(src), folder))
}
    sourceFolder("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/autots",recursive = TRUE))
```

However, I got this error:

```
> sourceFolder("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/autots",recursive = TRUE)
Error in environment(lstar) : object 'lstar' not found
Called from: environment(lstar)
```

I do not know how to fix it. The package that I try to install it as a source can be found here http://stat.snu.ac.kr/heeseok/autots

```
Any help, please?
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific than "it doesn't work"... right now the question doesn't really follow the guidelines for a good question.  That said, i don't think there is a sourceFolder() function in base R.   The help files ?source  suggests one way to "source a bunch of files."

Comment: @Elin Thank you so much for your comment. I have edited and update my question.

Comment: Is it to install the package? Any reason not to use `install.packages("/path/to/autots", repos=NULL)`? Else, it seems to me the error arises from `zzz.R` which does not contain functions, you might want to ignore that file.

Comment: I ve made some edits to the zzz file but I don't now if the package will work after :[